# add multiple overlays to a single image with ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, overlay, transition

How am I supposed to add two transition animations to the same image in the video with ffmpeg command? I want the image to slide from left to right and after a while back from right to left... This command is for left to right

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='min(-1.5*w+5*w*t,5)':y=H/2-h/2'" -y output.mp4
```

Comment: Make 2 videos (one for each side) and then combine the two output into new final video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to do this. One is to provide a clipped oscillating function, similar to the expression for `x` used in the drawtext filter [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/17512/1871).

The other method is use a conditional expression, shown below.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i image.png
  -filter_complex
     "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lt(t,8),min(-1.5*w+5*w*t,5),5-5*w*(t-8))':y=H/2-h/2'"
  -y output.mp4
```

Here's the slide out starts at `t=8s`.